# Have Column Start Immediately Below Column Above in Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible using Bootstrap to have this layout on small and larger devices:

```
-----
|A| |
|-|B|
|C| |
-----
```

and this layout on xs devices:

```
---
|A|
|-|
|B|
|-|
|C|
---
```

In the first example, C must be immediately below A, not starting at the bottom of B in a new row.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">A</div>
  <div class="col-sm-offset-6 col-sm-6">B</div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[See Bootply Example](http://www.bootply.com/Mhi464pmaH) - I used MD there, but the effect is the same. Just use SM for small and large devices. It will do what you want.